# Need help Exporting a dataframe into multiple CSVs based on a the values in a column - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, export

I am trying to export a dataframe into multiple csv, based on the values in the "Locations" column. I am new to all this but the code below seems to simply be rewriting the file over and over. I have 8 million rows of data with 500 unique Locations. I'd like to export all the columns in the dataframe, but only have the data corresponding to one Location for each. Example Columns are: ['Location', 'Time', 'Mark']

Additionally, I would like the filename of the CSV to be the "Location"

#SaveAs separate CSVs with Location as the filename:
df =

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A'] * 9 + ['B'] * 9,
                            list(range(1, 10)) + list(range(1, 10)),
                            [0]*2 + [1]*2 + [0]*2 + [1]*2 + [0]*5 + [1]*1 + [0]*1 + [1]*2 + [0]*1]).transpose(), columns = ['LOCATION', 'Time', 'Mark'])
df.head()
```

path = r'C:\Users\Y\Desktop\Files\ '

```
for ln in df.LOCATION.values:
    df_LN = df[df.LOCATION == ln]

    Output = path + ln + ".csv"

    df_LN.to_csv(Output, index=False)
```

Comment: can you post df.head() so we can see what could be done?

Comment: @ Gokturk Sahin, i just put an example df in the question - it works on this dataframe, but when I test it on the real file, it just keep rewriting over the file. Whether they are strings. Is there somehow a limit to the number of rows it will loop over?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to ouput to a different file for each index. This can be done with the `groupby` function;

```
path = r'C:\Users\Y\Desktop\Files\\'

# index as a column 
df = df.reset_index()

# group by index ('a', 'b', ...)
for label, group in df.groupby('index'):

    # create the ouput file's name
    out_path = path + label + '.csv'

    # group is a df
    group.to_csv(out_path, index=False)
```